# Have .gitignore to NOT ignore an .htaccess file within top level directory

Tags: git, .htaccess, commit

I am trying to ignore ALL files except the .htaccess file within the www directory.

I have this:

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
!/www/.htaccess
```

And I have also tried this:

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
!www/.htaccess
```

When I run `git status` I don't see .htaccess as being an added file. I have tried committing the .gitignore file. Still nothing. I am missing something obvious, no?

**Update**

I have also tried these:

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
*/\.htaccess

# Except these files
!.gitignore
!www/\.htaccess
```

and

```
# Ignore everything in this directory
*
*/.htaccess

# Except these files
!.gitignore
!www/.htaccess
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried some sample steps on my machine, try them and check if they work for you.

```
cd ~/Desktop/test
mkdir www && touch .gitignore www/.gitkeep www/.htaccess www/file1 www/file2
git init && git add www/.gitkeep && git commit -m "gitkeep to make www trackable"
```

Doing `git status` will now show you

```
.gitignore
www/.htaccess
www/file1
www/file2
```

Now, In your .gitignore file, add the following two entries

```
www/*
!www/.htaccess
```

Doing a `git status` now shows

```
.gitignore
www/.htaccess
```

You can now add these two files using `git add .` and commit them.

Also, once you are convinced that the said commands work, you can remove the `www/.gitkeep` I generate in my example (It was added to keep `www` trackable, git doesn't version folders) and add `www/.htaccess` instead to reduce the overhead of redundant files.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
*/.htaccess
!www/.htaccess
```

Comment: tried that. committed .gitignore and still not seeing .htaccess coming up

Answer (score 1):

In my own experience the below solution is much more simple than the accepted answer.

**Add the following to your .gitignore file**

```
www/*
!www/.htaccess
```

Now you are done!

**The Explanation**

To break it down `www/*` ignores all occupants of the "www" directory but not the directory itself, as the `/www` command would.

Next we declare our explicit exception `!www/.htaccess` as you've attempted in your question.

It only takes two lines in the .gitignore file and it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem! `www` and `!www/.htaccess` meant that Git was told to ignore the whole folder "www", so it would never see the .htaccess file even if you allowed it. By changing the first statement to `www/*` (meaning "track the folder www itself, but not any of the files within it"), it allowed the second statement (`!www/.htaccess`) to find the htaccess file. To do that, I had to do the equivalent of `git add www` to start tracking the folder, and I then saw the htaccess show up in the staging (and no other files, just as I intended).

Answer (score 0):

If you're in main folder of your project:

```
/.htaccess
```